# How can we use WebElement.FindElement() or findElements() method on a single WebElement object, even if its a method of WebDriver interface?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, coding

I am a newbie in Selenium and Java.

- Now, is this code correct. How can I call `findElement()` or
  `findElements()` method on a single WebElement? I want to store text
  of `td[1]` node.
- Why are we doing Method chaining here?

```java
    List<WebElement> sections = driver.findElements(By.tagname("section"));
    String td1 = sections.get(0).findElements(By.tagName("tfoot")).get(1).findElements(By.tagName("td")).get(0).getText());
```

Html DOM code:

```html
    <section>
        <h2>product table</h2>
        <div>
                        <table class="right">
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr class="product">
                                    <td>Product 1
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="rt">323.00</td>
                                    <td class="rt">
                                        6
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="rt">
                                        6
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="rt">&nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: code looks correct what is the issue you facing

Comment: I want to understand the logic behind calling findElement method on a WebElement,  instead of driver reference.

Comment: Did the answer help ?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Please accept it by pressing the tick sign near to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find a element as

```
elem = driver.findElement(somelocator) or
elem.findElement(someLocator)
```

Now consider a use case where you have to find all options inside a header

[image]

here the header locator is:

```
//ol[@role="presentation"]
```

Now as the icon are children of the header element and header element is unique , we can use this as reference to find all the child elements

eg:

```
   //ol[@role="presentation"]/li[3]
   //ol[@role="presentation"]/li[4] ... and so on
```

[image]

now you can use locator as :

```
 elem = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ol[@role=\"presentation\"]/li"))[3] or
 elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ol[@role=\"presentation\"]/li[3]"))
```

**Another good option is to find the header element and call child from it**

```
 header = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ol[@role=\"presentation\"]"))
 elem   = header.findElements(By.tagname("li"))[3]
```

here it does the same thing calls all child elements of header tag , this look more cleaner